# Is the Weasley's residence "the Burrow" in the magical or non-magical realm?

Tags: harry-potter

Based solely on what appears in the Harry Potter movies, there appear to be inconsistencies with the existence of some things in the Muggle vs magical realms.

In *Harry Potter*, there are clearly magical realms overlaid on the everyday Muggle world, which are invisible/inaccessible to Muggles, at least without magical intervention. Among them, I believe are:

- Diagon Alley
- Platform 9-3/4
- Hogwarts Castle
- The Black family residence at Grimmauld Place
- The Ministry of Magic

The Burrow seems to be an inconsistency - it appears to exist in the real world, despite open displays of magic, including the family "clock" device showing the location of various family members, and the dishes washing themselves, and even the improbable structure itself - it seems to need magic just to hold itself up. It ought to be in the magical realm, but there is never any indication that anyone crosses between magical and Muggle realms when arriving or leaving.

In which realm (magical or Muggle) does the Burrow exist? How is this apparent inconsistency resolved?

Comment: Could you split this out into separate questions.

Comment: @Valorum I've rewritten the question; should I be asking about The Burrow and the train separately?

Comment: I'd say so. The Burrow is a single compact location, while the train travels over a long distance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the Hogwarts Express in the magical or non-magical realm?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223849/is-the-hogwarts-express-in-the-magical-or-non-magical-realm)

Comment: (I don't know why @Valorum asked you to make these two separate questions, given that they both have the same answer.)

Comment: There is no realm. The whole magic world exists in our (boring) muggle world.

Answer (score 10):

There's no such thing as "magical realm". All Harry Potter magic world is exactly in the same Earth as the Muggle world, but just hidden by charms of protection and concealment.

For example, the Leaky Cauldron is out there in London at plain sight... If you're a mage. Muggles simply don't see it.

> The people hurrying by didn’t glance at it. Their eyes slid from the big book shop on one side to the record shop on the other as if they couldn’t see the Leaky Cauldron at all. In fact, Harry had the most peculiar feeling that only he and Hagrid could see it.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*. Chapter Five: Diagon Alley.

We can assume that the Burrow has some sort of Muggle repellents and/or concealment charms, just like Hogwarts, to avoid Muggle neighbors intruding and discovering magic. That said, I don't recall a canon source where it is explicitly stated.